# htaccess RewriteRule redirect a url containing +

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uri

I want to redirect a url such as `www.example.com/new+uploads` to another page using `htaccess`

What I have tried is:

```
RewriteRule ^new%2Buploads$ /index.php?iid=5
and
RewriteRule ^new+uploads$ /index.php?iid=5
```

neither of these work, if i remove the + sign, the rewrite works fine, i've searched multiple threads on here and google and I cant find anything explaining it!

Comment: Try using a space in place of the '+'.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/top played$ /index.php?iid=5` gives me a `500 internal server error`

Comment: Right, that was stupid of me, sorry about that. Try `\+`. If that doesn't work, `\s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^new\+uploads$ /index.php?iid=5
```